# InvalidOperationException MVC 4 View Master not Found

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm building a function that returns information from a view in a database.

My Controller looks like so

```
         [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StudentsLookup(string Firstname, string Lastname)
    {
        //checks for vaild name
        var nameCount = db.v_Directory.Where(name => name.LAST_NAME == Lastname).Count();

        //searches by lastname
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Firstname) && nameCount > 0)

        {
            object c = db.v_Directory.Where(name => name.LAST_NAME == Lastname).ToList();
            return View("StudentsLookup", c);
        }

        //searches by fullname
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Firstname) && nameCount > 0)
        {
            object l = db.v_Directory.Where(name => name.LAST_NAME == Lastname && name.FIRST_NAME == Firstname).ToList();
            return View("StudentLookup", l);

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Search";
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

The function that only searches for last name returns a valid view, the search for first and last name returns the exception. I'm new to coding and very confused. Debugging show data being transferred through the model in both cases.

The View looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "StudentsLookup";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>StudentsLookup</h2>

@{ 
        if (Model != null)
        {
            <h1>Possible Matches</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> STUDENT_ID </th>
                    <th> FirstName </th> 
                    <th> LastName </th>
                    <th> USER_NAME </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var person in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@person.STUDENT_ID</td>
                        <td>@person.FIRST_NAME </td>
                        <td>@person.LAST_NAME </td>
                        <td>@person.USER_NAME</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        }
}
```

I get the error, InvalidOperationException: The view 'StudentLookup' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
Message='bool' does not contain a definition for 'STUDENT_ID'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found that additional 's' were missing in `return View("StudentLookup", l);`, it should be `return View("StudentsLookup", l);` if your view named 'StudentsLookup'. Any returned view name from controller should have exactly same name with available view pages.

Comment: Wow! incredible oversight on my part! Thanks.